# Get Specific ID of user in search function c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach (uspSearchPatient pat in search)
{
    HyperLink ViewProfile = new HyperLink();
    TableCell patient = new TableCell();
    TableCell profile = new TableCell();
    TableRow trPatient = new TableRow();

    ViewProfile.Text = "View Profile";
    ViewProfile.ID = pat.PatientID;
    Session["PatientID"] = pat.PatientID;
    ViewProfile.NavigateUrl = "ViewProfileByDoctor.aspx";
    profile.Controls.Add(ViewProfile);
    patient.Text = pat.Patient +"("+ pat.PatientID +")";
    trPatient.Cells.Add(patient);
    trPatient.Cells.Add(profile);

    tbSearchResults.Rows.Add(trPatient);             
}
```

I have tried this. But it only returns the last patient ID. I want to get the first Patients ID

Comment: Hi. Can you edit your question and add more details about what you want. Your title says specific id, your question talking about first and last ids and some sort of returning. Can't see any returns in your code. Your just iterate through your (probably) search results.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to obtain, but based upon the fact you set `Session["PatientID"]` within the loop, this would result in this session variable to be set to the last PatientID, because the previous set value is overwritten.